# AJax not calling php file correctly, html forms

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

UPDATE:
This is the error:

```
412 (Precondition Failed)
```

I am trying to call a php script from ajax, I currently have the below ajax, which when the button in the form (also below) is clicked will call a php script passing it the form data, which will then be submitted to the database.

However, it is not working; and what's more I am just getting a blank error back, so I do not even know what is going wrong.

Could someon please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

HTML form:

```
<form name="report-form" id="report-form" action="" method="POST">              
                <textarea id="reason-box" type="text" name="reason-box" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="160" onkeypress=""></textarea>    
                <input id="reportedID" name="reportedID" type="text" />
                <!--<input id="report-submit" value="" name="submit" type="submit" onclick="submitReport()"/>   -->
                <button id="report-submit" name="submit" onclick="submitReport()"></button>

            </form>
```

AJax call:

```
function submitReport()
        {           

            var ID=$('#reportedID').val();
            var reason=$('#reason-box').val();

            var  formData = "ID="+ID+"&reason="+reason;
            alert(formData);

         //This code will run when the user submits a report.
           $.ajax(
            {           
               url: 'submit_report.php',
               type: "POST",
               data: formData,
               success: function(data)
               {                     
                 alert("Report Submitted!");
               },           
               error: function(xhr,err)
               {                     
                  alert(err.message);
                    alert("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
               }
           });

        }
```

Now I have already tested the php script, and that works fine, the problem started when I added the ajax call so I know it is something to do with the ajax not the php.

Comment: What error are you getting back? A 404? a 500?

Comment: That is one of the problems, I am getting a blank error back. Not sure if it is the code in the error: section that is wrong.

Comment: For troubleshooting set success function to be: `console.log(data);`  And set the error function to: `console.log(xhr); console.log(err);` Then check out the console output

Comment: Can you post the submit_report.php? Even if it works during your internal testing, we still need to see what it's returning. Also, hit control+shift+i in your browser and go to the console and report and errors.

Comment: First of all use `event.preventDefault()` in your  submit code to prevent submitting the form.

Comment: Ok thanks, I shall try that now.

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for the correct callback function for `error:` in your `$.ajax`.

Comment: I am trying to get it to log, but the problem is the page refreshes due to the form being submitted. Whereabouts exactly am I putting this 'event.preventDefault()' ? In the ajax call?

Comment: I have updated the question with the error

Answer (score 1):

This should correct the problem with submitting:

1. Your jQuery Ajax call won't succeed because the `POST` data isn't supplied in the correct format.
2. If the ajax should succeed the form is also posted resulting in a `405` error.

```html
 <button id="report-submit" name="submit" onclick="submitReport(event)"></button>
```

```js
function submitReport(event)
{           
    event.preventDefault();
    ....... // your code

}
```

Now the default action of your form will be prevented (resulting in a 405 error). And only the ajax request is submitted.

In the button element we pass the `event` object on to the function. We use `event.preventDefault()` to make sure the button doesn't run it's default action, which is submitting the form.

You could also prevent this by deleting the form element as a wrapper, but maybe you want to use other features (like validation) on the form.

Form data in a jQuery ajax request needs to be an object called data:

```
var formData = {"ID" : ID, "reason" : reason};
```

jQuery will reform this to a correct query string for the submit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately this did not fix the problemm

Comment: How would the syntax look in my example then sorry?

Comment: hmmm, that does not seem to be working either. It says success, but does not actually submit the query. But there is also no sql error, so I know it is no the sql.

Comment: It will still work without "event" as a parameter, but this method is preferred for legibility.

Comment: Yes I says success, but the php script is not being called anymore.

Comment: As when I put an alert in the php script, the alert does not run.

Comment: The response is: 302
Moved Temporarily

Comment: Yes I realise that now sorry, after removing the redirect yes it gives me the 200 OK response.

Comment: In my PHP script, how would I now refer to the pieces of data? Previously I have been using: $reason=$_POST['reason-box'];
 $ID=$_POST['reportedID'];. However, do I now need to change this?

Comment: @CallumHolden, could you help me clean up these comments.

Comment: @CallumHolden,also since this fixed your problem, please accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<form name="report-form" id="report-form" action="" method="POST">              
      <textarea id="reason-box" type="text" name="reason-box" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="160"></textarea>    
      <input id="reportedID" name="reportedID" type="text" />
      <button id="report-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
    var $ = jQuery
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var data = "";
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit_report.php", 
            data: data,
             success: function(data)
               {                     
                 alert("Report Submitted!");
               },           
               error: function(xhr,err)
               {                     
                  alert(err.message);
                    alert("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
               }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and then use `$reason=$_POST['reason-box'];` and `$ID=$_POST['reportedID'];` inside your PHP script

Answer (score 0):

this is optional  to choose the form for submitting data or you can do it without the HTML form this is what i do

```
 <textarea id="reasonbox" type="text" name="reason-box" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="160" onkeypress=""></textarea>    
<input id="reportedID" name="reportedID" type="text" />
 <button id="report-submit"  ></button>
```

and the using folloing javascript and jquery style

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

 $("#report-submit").click(function(){
            try
            {
                $.post("your php page address goes here like /mypage.php",
                    {
//in this area you put the data that is going to server like line below
                        'reasonbox':$("#reason-box").val().trim(),
                        'reportedID':$("#reportedID").val().trim()

                    }, function(data){
                        data=data.trim();
//this is data is sent back from server you can send back data that you want
//like message or json array
                    });
            }
            catch(ex)
            {
                alert(ex);
            }
        });

});
</script>
```

I hope it helps